Having issue with AWS Cloudfront, Route53 mapping to AWS EC2
I have hosted domain.com (website) in an EC2 instance and I have created the Cloudfront distribution and mapped the Origin to EC2 DNS. So far good.
In my Route 53 I have created a CNAME record and added cloudfront DISTRIBUTION url i.e www.domain.com -> <distribution_URL>. Now when i type the www.domain in browser my site is opening correctly but when i try to give domain.com it was going to 404 page.
I tried adding A record with Alias of Distribution URL but it is not working
Route53 Entry - https://prnt.sc/KHGYF9MNY4EJ
Cloudfront Entry - https://prnt.sc/UR-QcaIQeenx
Tried adding domain.com - https://prnt.sc/2Xe8GqMdIK5t
Not working

You have only added www.domain.com as an alternate domain in CloudFront. You also need to add domain.com as an alternate domain.
